# Angular 2 and npm start: How to change polling interval?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

I'm working through the Angular 2 tutorial (https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) and using `npm start` to watch the TypeScript files and automatically transpile and reload the built-in web server when they change.

It works fine but there seems to be a lot of lag. Sometimes it can take 10 seconds before it notices that the files have changed. Once it sees the changes, it compiles and reloads very quickly.

Does anyone know if there's a way to set the polling interval to something faster?

I looked in the documentation for `npm start` and for the concurrently module, and I couldn't find any documented settings to change this.

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "test": "live-server --open=src/unit-tests.html"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^1.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "lite-server": "^1.3.1",
    "typescript": "^1.7.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a **typescript** bug from version 1.7.4+.

In the `package.json`, write `"typescript": "1.7.3"` and then execute `npm update` to install that version.

Comment: That makes a big difference. It sees the changes almost instantly now. Thanks.